# Makie returning empty plots

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I am new to julia, I want plot a simple scatterplot from a dataframe where the colors are coded as String7 hexadecimal code, a snapshot,

```
 Row │ x      y      ncv_color 
     │ Int64  Int64  String7   
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │   120   4180  #005529
   2 │   120   3890  #004903
   3 │   110   4670  #004E66
   4 │   120   8270  #004A99
   5 │   120   9620  #005C5A
```

when I use the following code to draw a scatterplot, it works.

```
scatter(df.x, df.y)
```

[image: scatter plot]

Although when I use
As suggested by @ginkul using this

```
scatter(df2, df2, color=df.ncv_color)
```

I get `FigureAxisPlot()` as output and no plot is shown.

Any help would be appreciated.

`versioninfo`

```
Julia Version 1.6.3
Commit ae8452a9e0 (2021-09-23 17:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: AMD EPYC 7542 32-Core Processor
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-11.0.1 (ORCJIT, znver2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing `ncv_color` as a `Symbol`. You can actually pass `Symbol` as color, for example `:red`, but since there is no such color as `ncv_color` nothing can be displayed. `scatter` doesn't know that you're implying a column of `df`. You need to pass your array explicitly.

```
scatter(df.x, df.y, color = df.ncv_color)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I figured that's not the problem, it's because Makie scatter can not convert `String7` to color codes. After this line, 
`df.ncv_color = convert(Vector{String}, df.ncv_color)` , `scatter(df.x, df.y, color=:ncv_color)` started working.

Comment: I meant to say that's not the _only_ problem